# Batch gradient descent algorithm does not converge

Tags: c++, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement batch grandient descent algorithm for my machine learning homework. I have a training set, whose x value is around `10^3` and y value is around `10^6`. I'm trying to find the value of `[theta0, theta1]` which makes `y = theta0 + theta1 * x` converge. I set the learning rate to `0.0001` and maximum interation to `10`. Here's my code in Qt.

```
QVector<double> gradient_descent_batch(QVector<double> x, QVector<double>y)
{
    QVector<double> theta(0);
    theta.resize(2);

    int size = x.size();

    theta[1] = 0.1;
    theta[0] = 0.1;

    for (int j=0;j<MAX_ITERATION;j++)
    {
        double dJ0 = 0.0;
        double dJ1 = 0.0;

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            dJ0 += (theta[0] + theta[1] * x[i] - y[i]);
            dJ1 += (theta[0] + theta[1] * x[i] - y[i]) * x[i];
        }

        double theta0 = theta[0];
        double theta1 = theta[1];
        theta[0] = theta0 - LRATE * dJ0;
        theta[1] = theta1 - LRATE * dJ1;

        if (qAbs(theta0 - theta[0]) < THRESHOLD && qAbs(theta1 - theta[1]) < THRESHOLD)
            return theta;
    }

    return theta;
}
```

I print the value of `theta` every interation, and here's the result.

```
QVector(921495, 2.29367e+09) 
QVector(-8.14503e+12, -1.99708e+16) 
QVector(7.09179e+19, 1.73884e+23) 
QVector(-6.17475e+26, -1.51399e+30) 
QVector(5.3763e+33, 1.31821e+37) 
QVector(-4.68109e+40, -1.14775e+44) 
QVector(4.07577e+47, 9.99338e+50) 
QVector(-3.54873e+54, -8.70114e+57) 
QVector(3.08985e+61, 7.57599e+64) 
QVector(-2.6903e+68, -6.59634e+71)
```

I seems that theta will never converge. 
I follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783243/gradient-descent-algorithm-wont-converge) to set learning rate to `0.00000000000001` and maximum iteration to `20`. But it seems will not converge. Here's the result.

```
QVector(0.100092, 0.329367) 
QVector(0.100184, 0.558535) 
QVector(0.100276, 0.787503) 
QVector(0.100368, 1.01627) 
QVector(0.10046, 1.24484) 
QVector(0.100552, 1.47321) 
QVector(0.100643, 1.70138) 
QVector(0.100735, 1.92936) 
QVector(0.100826, 2.15713) 
QVector(0.100918, 2.38471) 
QVector(0.101009, 2.61209) 
QVector(0.1011, 2.83927) 
QVector(0.101192, 3.06625) 
QVector(0.101283, 3.29303) 
QVector(0.101374, 3.51962) 
QVector(0.101465, 3.74601) 
QVector(0.101556, 3.9722) 
QVector(0.101646, 4.1982) 
QVector(0.101737, 4.424) 
QVector(0.101828, 4.6496)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly your algorithm seems fine except that you should divide LRATE by size;

```
theta[0] = theta0 - LRATE * dJ0 / size;
theta[1] = theta1 - LRATE * dJ1 / size;
```

What I would suggest you should calculate cost function and monitor it;

[Cost function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3Eo.png)

Your cost should be decreasing on every iteration. If its bouncing back and forward you are using a large value of *learning rate*. I would suggest you to use 0.01 and do 400 iterations.

Comment: I tried dividing `size` when I updated `theta` and set `learning rate` and `iterations` as you suggested. However, the value of cost did not converge. Then I tried some smaller `learning rate`, and I finally found that `0.00000015` works well. Today I use `normal regression` to calculate `theta`. And I drew both lines and found they are much similar. I think it is `learining rate` that matters mostly.